# Unable to exit full screen mode in Eclipse

Tags: fullscreen, eclipse

I just installed Eclipse and went into the full screen mode but, unlike with other apps, the top bar wouldn't appear when I positioned the cursor at the top of the screen, so I was stuck in full screen and had to restart the computer.  Any way to exit the full screen mode in Eclipse?

Using MacOS 10.8.1, Eclipse 4.3.0 (Kepler).

Comment: What version of OS X and Eclipse are you running? If you look at [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/SAPFb.png) picture and [this one](http://i.stack.imgur.com/drlhz.png), you can see that it works fine for me. I am running OS X 10.8.4 with Eclipse Standard (Kepler Release; 20130614-0229)

Comment: also 10.8.1, Eclipse is 4.3.0 (Kepler)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Control-command-F toggles full screen in the version of Eclipse I have.

If it doesn't, try opening the preferences with command-, and setting a binding for a command like Toggle Full Screen in General > Keys.